# Instead of a single hostname specified on the command line, it reads in a list of multiple target IP addresses from a file

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, command-line, ip, hostname

I want to make it so that instead of a single hostname specified on the command line, it reads in a list of multiple target IP addresses from a file.

```
#!/bin/bash -
# bannergrab.sh
function isportopen ()
{
    (( $# < 2 )) && return 1                           # <1>
    local host port
    host=$1
    port=$2
    echo >/dev/null 2>&1  < /dev/tcp/${host}/${port}   # <2>
    return $?
}

function cleanup ()
{
    rm -f "$SCRATCH"
}

ATHOST="$1"
SCRATCH="$2"
if [[ -z $2 ]]
then
    if [[ -n $(type -p tempfile) ]]
    then
    SCRATCH=$(tempfile)
    else
        SCRATCH='scratch.file'
    fi
fi

trap cleanup EXIT                                      # <3>
touch "$SCRATCH"                                       # <4>

if isportopen $ATHOST 21    # FTP                  <5>
then
    # i.e., ftp -n $ATHOST 
    exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${ATHOST}/21                      # <6>
    echo -e 'quit\r\n' >&3                             # <7>
    cat <&3  >> "$SCRATCH"                             # <8>
fi

if isportopen $ATHOST 25    # SMTP
then
    # i.e., telnet $ATHOST 25 
    exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${ATHOST}/25
    echo -e 'quit\r\n' >&3
    cat <&3  >> "$SCRATCH"
fi

if isportopen $ATHOST 80    # HTTP
then
    curl -LIs "https://${ATHOST}"  >> "$SCRATCH"      # <9>
fi

cat "$SCRATCH"   # <10>
```

The file containing the list looks like it:

```
10.12.13.18
192.15.48.3
192.168.45.54
...
192.114.78.227
```

But how and where do I put a command like `set target file:/home/root/targets.txt`. Or it needs to be done in another way?

Comment: 1) fix your indentation. it makes it a lot easier for you _and_ anyone trying to help you to read your script if the code is indented properly. 2) You start with "Modify bannergrab.sh...", and that does have the sound of an assignment. Is it one? It can also come off a bit harshly, it's as if you're telling strangers on the internet to fix your script for you. 3) "I am assuming the file containing the list looks like [this]".. but you don't know? You probably need to know to be able to read the list properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to have "$1" represent a file containing a list of targets, instead of being just 1 target.

So you will need to englob the main part in a loop

```
ATHOSTFILE="$1"
SCRATCH="$2"
for ATHOST in $( cat "$ATHOSTFILE" ); do
   ... # (the rest of the actions here)
done
```

Note that the `$( cat "$ATHOSTFILE )` part will be replaced by the content of $ATHOSTFILE, and read "element by element", each element being splitted using $IFS (usually: any space(s) and tab(s) and newline(s) will act as separators).

There are quite a few other things to say about the syntax, and structure, but this should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Please don't suggest [`for i in (cat $file)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Using `while read i; do ...; done < "$file"` is safer and also avoids a useless use of cat. Yes, the `for` approach might work in this specific case, but it's bad practice and fragile.

Comment: @terdon: true. I'll edit. But then there needs to be only one item per line ...